# GPG confirmation form at LaunchPad fails to add key

Tags: gnupg, launchpad

I am trying to upload my PGP key to LaunchPad, but the last step fails. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Uploaded the public key to the Ubuntu server with `gpg --send-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com <KEY ID>`.
2. Published the key to the global key ring with `gpg --send-keys <KEY ID>`.
3. Added the key to LauchPad via the form to change pgp keys.
4. Decrypted the e-mail sent automatically from LaunchPad.

The LaunchPad e-mail contains an activation address like `https://launchpad.net/token/qwertyuiop`. It leads to a new form to confirm the key. When I click confirm it presents the following error:

> Launchpad could not import the OpenPGP key %{fingerprint}. Check that
> you published it correctly in the global     key ring (using gpg
> --send-keys KEY) and that you entered the fingerprint correctly (as produced by gpg --fingerpri    nt YOU). Try later or cancel your
> request.

The fingerprint is corrext and the key is already in the global key ring. What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

LaunchPad has finally validated the key. While I am not sure this was the cause, I deleted a forgotten key from an older system in the meantime.

First check existing keys:

```
$ gpg --list-keys
 /home/duque004/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
 ---------------------------------
 pub   rsa3072 2018-04-06 [SC] [expires: 2020-04-06]
       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 uid           [ultimate] Luís de Sousa <luis@mail.com>
 sub   rsa3072 2018-04-06 [E] [expires: 2020-04-06]
 
 sub   rsa4096 2020-07-06 [SC]
       YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
 uid           [ultimate] Luís de Sousa <luis@mail.com>
 sub   rsa4096 2020-07-06 [E]
```

Then delete the secret key:

```
gpg --delete-secret-keys XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Finally, remove the public key:

```
gpg --delete-key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```